# Add an effective index on a huge table

Tags: mysql, multithreading, indexing

I have a MySQL database table with more than 34M rows (and growing).

```
CREATE TABLE `sensordata` (
  `userID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `instrumentID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `utcDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataState` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Original',
  `gps` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `speed` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unitID` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `parameterID` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `originalData` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channelHashcode` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `settingHashcode` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(7) DEFAULT 'Offline',
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=98772 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I access this table from multiple threads (at least 400 threads) every minute to insert data into the table. 
As the table was growing, it was getting slower to read and write the data. One SELECT query used to take about 25 seconds, then I added a unique index

`UNIQUE INDEX idx_userInsDate ( userID,instrumentID,utcDateTime)`

This reduced the read time from 25 seconds to some milliseconds but it has increased the insert time as it has to update the index for each record.
Also If I run a SELECT query from multiple threads as the same time the queries take too long to return the data.

This is an example query

```
Select dateTime from sensordata WHERE userID = 'someUserID' AND instrumentID = 'someInstrumentID' AND dateTime between 'startDate' AND 'endDate' order by dateTime asc;
```

Can someone help me, to improve the table schema or add an effective index to improve the performance, please.

Thank you in advance

Comment: UNIQUE(...datetime) -- Red flag!  Is there a change that two rows will validly have the same datetime to the second?

Comment: did you try fixing your data as suggested?

Comment: @e4c5 yes I am working on it... the data is too big I have to be very careful about it...

Comment: yes, that's very true. Making the changes will take a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PRIMARY KEY` *is* a `UNIQUE` key.  Toss the redundant `UNIQUE(id)` !

Is `id` referenced by any other tables?  If not, then get rid of it all together.  Instead have just

```
PRIMARY KEY ( userID, instrumentID, utcDateTime)
```

That is, *if* that triple is guaranteed to be unique.  You mentioned DST -- use the datatype `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`.  Doing that, you can convert to `DATETIME` if needed, thereby eliminating one of the columns.

That one index (the PK) takes virtually no space since it is "clustered" with the data in InnoDB.

Your table is awfully fat with all those `VARCHARs`.  For example, `status` can be reduced to a 1-byte ENUM.  Others can be normalized.  Things like `speed` can be either a 4-byte `FLOAT` or some smaller `DECIMAL`, depending on how much range and precision you need.

With 34M wide rows, you have probably recently exceeded the cacheability of the RAM you have.  By making the row narrower, you will postpone that overflow.

Why attack the indexes?  Every `UNIQUE` (including `PRIMARY`) index is checked before allowing the row to be inserted.  By getting it down to 1 index, that minimizes the cost there.  (InnoDB really needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.)

`INT` is 4 bytes.  Do you have a billion instruments?  Maybe `instrumentID` could be `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`, which is 2 bytes, with a max of 64K?  Think about all the other IDs.

You have 400 `INSERTs`/minute, correct?  That is not bad.  If you get to  400/second, we need to have a different talk.

("Fill factor" is not tunable in MySQL because it does not make much difference.)

How much RAM do you have?  What is the setting for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Optimal is somewhere around 70% of *available* RAM.

Let's see your main queries; there may be other issues to address.

Comment: yes, after @e4c5's answer, I realised that the table is too fat and must be restructured... id is not referenced by any other table, I will remove it. userID and instrumentID are strings not numbers so cant change them but I will change speed,unitID,parameterID and others

Comment: using ENUM will be perfect... I will definitely change dataState and status to ENUM...

Comment: In some cases, utcDateTime and dateTime are same like for the instruments in the UK, but they will change in summer for DST... I can get rid of dateTime column but then I will have to process each record to change UTC to local time zone when visualising/processing the data  which will take time so I think i will keep it.

Comment: The `TIMESTAMP` values to not repeat for one hour every year, like `DATETIME`.  A `TIMESTAMP` can be converted (in `SELECT`) to localtime (to account for DST) when needed.  I'm arguing to get rid of any column being declared `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 1):

1st of all: Avoid varchars for indexes and especially IDs. Each character position in the varchar generates an own index-entry internally!

2nd: Your select uses dateTime, your index is set to utcDateTime. It will only take userID and instrumentID and ignore the utcDateTime-Part.

Advise: Change your data types for the ids and change your index to match the query (dateTime, not utcDateTime)

Using an index decreases your performance on inserts, unluckily, there is nothing such as a fill factor for indexes in mysql right now. So the best thing you can do is try the indexes to be as small as possible.

Another approach on heavily loaded databases with random access would be: write to an unindexed table, read from an indexed one. At a given time, build the indexes and swap the tables (may require a third table for the index creation while leaving the other ones untouched in between).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I added a unique index so that there are no duplicate records for the same user+instrument+utcdateTime, there can be some duplicate records for user+instrument+dateTime in case of daylight saving time change...

Comment: You are creating huge indexes on your tables. This is going to slow down your updates/deletes/inserts big times. Eventually even the select operations will be slow unless you are on SSD because random IO is much much slower than sequential IO

Comment: yes I should rather SELECT utcDateTime and not dateTime... I will change  the query but others have pointed out correctly, the schema of the table should be improved

Answer (score 1):

It's not the indexes at fault here. It's your data types. As the size of the data on disk grows, the speed of all operations decrease. Indexes can certainly help speed up selects - provided your data is properly structured - but it appears that it isnt

```
CREATE TABLE `sensordata` (
  `userID` int,  /* shouldn't this have a foreign key constraint? */
  `instrumentID` int,
  `utcDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
/* what exactly are you putting here? Are you sure it's not causing any reduncy? */
  `data` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
 /* your states will be a finite number of elements. They can be represented by constants in your code or a set of values in a related table */
  `dataState` int,
/* what's this? Sounds like what you are saving in location */
  `gps` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` point,
  `speed` float,
  `unitID` int DEFAULT '1',
/* as above */
  `parameterID` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
/* are you sure this is different from data? */
  `originalData` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channelHashcode` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `settingHashcode` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
/* as above and isn't this the same as */
  `status` int,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=98772 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: In fact, it is the indexes "fault": Using an index speeds up searching for a record, but decreases the insert performance as the index has to be rebuilt

Comment: @Psi that's correct, this is what I stated in the question, Do you have a suggestion to improve the indexes, please

Comment: @psi, I am well aware that indexes slow down insert/update/delete but the data has to be properly organized

Comment: Indexes are completely useless when you data is totally unstructured.